# how to know the type of scan results using zxing for android

Tags: android, zxing

I have managed to build the core and and I have imported the source "android" and it worked perfectly, but I want to know the result type of scan using zxing "eg:
URL, TEL,ISBN...." . I need it to make some optionals Treatments  in
my application. How can I do it?

If it is possible to do it "eg: contact name and phone number coded
with QR" how can i extract the phone number and title separately. !! I
looked for many classes like ParsedResult.java and
TelParsedResult.java on the package name core\com\google\zxing\client
\result but i misuse and can't exploit it.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to use zxing is to use it through the intents interface, using the intents integrator. However, doing it this way means you don't have access to the `Result` object, just a simple string of the contents. If you're going the hardcore route, you can import the whole zxing tree into your source (assuming you can comply with the license) and use `ResultParser.parseResult(Result theResult)`.

My recommendation would be to just use the intents integrator and parse it yourself. The format is very simple, so it should be trivial to split apart with basic string functions.

Comment: firstly thank you for your quick response. about your recommendation i think if i use the own library of zxing directely to parse data better than do it with my algorithm , therefore we never lost time and save battery life,processor treatments ...

Answer (score -1):

The result that you get after scanning is a string. Parse the string and you will know the type of qrcode.
Each type of QR code has a specific start, like for Location QR the result we get starts with "geo:", for URL QR the result starts with "http:" or "www.".
So try parsing the result that you get after scanning the QR code.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the `ZBarSymbol` class object?

[ZBarSymbol Class Reference](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/ZBarSymbol.html)

Comment: This is C, which is difficult to use on Android, and does not appear to contain any logic to parse the content of a barcode.

Comment: I don't think so, which is why I didn't downvote it. Somebody else did. Relax!

Comment: Eh? I can't help if you're somehow still convinced I'm the down-voter. I get downvotes all the time, who cares? Your answer actually doesn't address the question. The OP needs Java (Android), and parsing of the contents, not the barcode. I don't think you should be surprised, let alone feel upset, that someone (maybe the questioner?) simply thought it was not a good answer to this particular question.